# El banner de gbianchi con el tema en modo oscuro de Stack Overflow es ilegible

Tags: bug, estado-por-diseño, modo-oscuro, anuncios-de-ayuda

La imagen de *@gbianchi* tiene un fondo transparente. Esto hace que al usar el tema en modo oscuro de *Stack Overflow en inglés*, las letras negras coinciden con el fondo y se hace complicado de leer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Banner de gbianchi](https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/16438061397862254717)

Dejo una captura de pantalla de cómo se ve en *Stack Overflow* con el modo oscuro:

[image: Banner con texto ilegible en modo oscuro]

Comment: Bien visto!!! Avisemos...

Comment: Recomendaría que según el modo oscuro o no se coloque un fondo claro en el contenedor (`div`) donde se encuentra la imagen. Eso evitaría la necesidad de estar editándo imágenes con fondo transparentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I apologise for writing in English. I would appreciate translation of this answer.)

I talked to our ads team. They said that the problem is that some banners were created with a transparent background. The second problem is that we have tons of banners and only part of them have a transparent background. Considering the amount of banners, it seems to be impossible to identify all problematic ones manually.

We need your help here! When you see a banner with a transparent background, please [report the banner](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/24/report-this-ad-beta-provides-more-control-over-your-advertising-experience/) with a note that we need to replace it with the same one but different background. The ads team should take care about the rest.

---

(Pido disculpas por escribir en inglés. Agradecería la traducción de esta respuesta).

Le hablé a nuestro equipo de anuncios. Dijeron que el problema es que se crearon algunos banners con un fondo transparente. El segundo problema es que tenemos montones de banners y solo parte de ellos tienen un fondo transparente. Considerando la cantidad de banners, parece imposible identificar todos los problemáticos uno por uno manualmente.

¡Necesitamos tu ayuda aquí! Cuando veas un banner con un fondo transparente, puedes [reportar el banner](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/24/report-this-ad-beta-provides-more-control-over-your-advertising-experience/) con una nota de que debemos reemplazarlo con el mismo, pero de fondo diferente. El equipo de anuncios debe atender el resto.

Comment: we have all the ads in a thread.. can you just take them from there?

Comment: It is not that easy to find those banners among all the banners. There are too many banners with very little navigation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for raising this. We're still seeing some of these errors from dark mode and we've added this to our backlog to address. It may take some time to get to this, with some of our higher priority bugs, but it's on our radar. Thanks!

---

Gracias por plantear esto. Todavía estamos viendo algunos de estos errores del modo oscuro y lo hemos agregado a nuestro trabajo pendiente para solucionarlo. Puede que lleve algún tiempo llegar a esto, con algunos de nuestros errores de mayor prioridad, pero está en nuestro radar. ¡Gracias!