# El modo oscuro ya está disponible en Stack Overflow en español

Tags: discusión, interfaz-de-usuario, modo-oscuro

Muchas gracias a [@Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) por la traducción.

---

¿Qué puede ser lo difícil al crear el modo oscuro para el sitio? Incluso [extensiones de terceros](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336626/274323) pueden hacerlo. Pero cada vez que pensábamos en una implementación, [un gran número de complejidades técnicas](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/issues/297) ocurrían.  La situación cambió con “[Stacks styles](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/)” y la migración de la mayor parte del sitio a ese diseño. Gracias a ello, en julio de 2019 empezamos a considerar seriamente la posibilidad de crear el modo oscuro. [A principios de 2020, Aaron exploró la posibilidad de añadir el modo oscuro](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/356) y a finales de marzo, la [versión beta estuvo disponible en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/564240).

¡Estamos contentos de anunciar que el modo oscuro ya está disponible también para todos los usuarios registrados en Stack Overflow en español!

[image: Dark mode screenshot]

Por ahora, el modo oscuro solamente está disponible en el sitio principal de los Stack Overflow internacionales. La capacidad de soportar el modo oscuro en los metas, incluyendo MSE, al igual que el resto de sitios de la red de SE, sigue en cuestión.

[Para leer más sobre el modo oscuro puedes visitar el blog de Aaron.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/)

#### Cómo activarlo

Para activarlo, visita [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current). Entra y encuentra la sección titulada “Tema” en la cabecera de la página. Tienes tres opciones: claro, oscuro y “valor del sistema” la cual ajustará el tema según lo que tu sistema prefiere.

[image: Captura de pantalla de la página de preferencias mostrando las tres opciones: claro, oscuro y valor del sistema.]

#### Cómo reportar un error

Si encuentras un error, por favor haz una pregunta en Meta Stack Overflow en español o en Meta Stack Overflow en inglés.

¡Esperamos escuchar vuestros comentarios constructivos!

Comment: Los snippets de código me parecen muy limpios y funcionales, de cierto modo me hacen sentir como si estuviera en uno de los niveles de Mario Bros

Comment: Hermoso!!! gracias por estos avances a la página.

Comment: Vale aclarar que no se puede hacer desde el perfil de Meta. Hay que ir al perfil dentro del sitio principal.

Comment: Muchas gracias por esto, yo estaba usando user scripts para conseguirlo. Tras probarlo, veo que no funciona ni en meta, ni en el chat. Esperemos que se solucione pronto!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' All the thanks to the devs, who made a reality. I am the one who only posted the announcement =) I've sent you an email with the text. Could you please tell me if it works for you?

Comment: Recientemente el modo oscuro esta provocando esto con los anuncios que tienen fondo transparente (suponiendo fondo blanco) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T7IW.png, no se donde reportarlo.

Comment: @F.Igor ¿Podría informar de este anuncio y cambiaremos el fondo? Para hacerlo, haga clic en "Report this ad" debajo de un banner. Luego seleccione "Other" y agregue una nota que necesitamos para cambiar el fondo. ¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: @Nicolas se reportó en [El banner de gbianchi con el tema en modo oscuro de Stack Overflow es ilegible](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4672/83) y [Modo oscuro… las ayudas en forma de publicidad no se ven](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4907/83)

Comment: Cuando se pondra un modo oscuro aca?

Comment: @JuanRivera Ya está disponible =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky en donde puedo cambiarlo? solo lo tengo en stackoverflow español no en meta :c