# Modo oscuro... las ayudas en forma de publicidad no se ven

Tags: bug

las publicidades en modo oscuro de ayuda, no se ven...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: fedo queria que se notara que ahora es aca... porque el otro se relacionaba con el sitio en ingles...

Comment: 5 de enero del 2021, el problema persiste. Justo iba a crear una pregunta al respecto